# How to undelete a directory on btrfs multi-disk volume

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery, btrfs

I'm new to btrfs and have an issue. I originally posted this as an answer on an identical question but i have been told that I'm supposed to ask it again.

First things first. I have exhausted Google and tried the btrfs-undelete script. I've had no luck recovering my directory. I need to recover it asap as important files are on the drive also that we need and I have it unmounted until we figure this out.

I've tried a few blocks and I get the same error here.

I've tried btrfs restore as you see here.

$ sudo btrfs restore /dev/sde /media -v -i -t 1060780900352 parent transid verify failed on 1060780900352 wanted 39805 found 39797 parent transid verify failed on 1060780900352 wanted 39805 found 39797 parent transid verify failed on 1060780900352 wanted 39805 found 39797 parent transid verify failed on 1060780900352 wanted 39805 found 39797 Ignoring transid failure Couldn't setup extent tree Couldn't read fs root: -2 extent buffer leak: start 1060780900352 len 16384

My setup: I have two 4tb drives in a single btrfs cluster in raid 0. I know, no need to mention how bad that idea was. So my wife is learning Linux and well let's say she's never allowed near the server again. She ran the command sudo rm -rf /media/Movies trying to delete a single file and that is why we are here.

Well, I had 1.5TB in that folder of hundreds of files. I could either spend another 2 months ripping all my DVDs again or recover my directory. I'm really surprised btrfs doesn't have better documentation on file recovery. Or a tool that can be used for this purpose. First thing I did when she told me about it is stop all processes writing to that mount, remove the btrfs volume from fstab and reboot. For some reason umount never works for me on the btrfs mounts.

So here is a partial lsblk. sde and sdb1 are both in the volume together. I'm still not sure why sde shows no partitions.

NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT sdb 8:16 0 3.7T 0 disk └─sdb1 8:17 0 3.7T 0 part sde 8:64 0 3.7T 0 disk sdf 8:80 0 1.8T 0 disk └─sdf1 8:81 0 1.8T 0 part /media

Here is my entry in fstab: UUID=7ffdecf9-af9a-4299-b697-4fc375bac3b1 /media btrfs defaults

So when I ran a sudo btrfs restore -s /dev/sde /tmp it restored some files. I had to stop it because I can't store 4TB on my root partition. I'd like to either recover /media/Movies from sde and sdb1. Or I would be willing to restore a snapshot but only of that one subdirectory as other data changes hourly.

So where can I start? I have run btrfs-find-root /dev/sde and sdb1 and have the output files but I don't want to run the btrfs-undelete script since I get the errors above. I also noticed a strange line in the btrfs-undelete script I got from here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.btrfs/22560

In the script, it references /dev/mapper/queen-home Now I've only been using Linux for a year now full time but I've never heard of that file.

Any ideas, questions, comments? I'm desperate so any help I can find would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you manage to recover the files? Here's pointer to cleanup script: https://gist.github.com/Changaco/45f8d171027ea2655d74